# Dynamic script for submitting a form

Tags: javascript

How can i write this dynamically to use on a number of forms?

```
function submitform()
{
    if(document.hotelfrm.onsubmit &&
    !document.hotelfrm.onsubmit())
    {
        return;
    }
 document.hotelfrm.submit();
}

form name="hotelfrm" id="hotelfrm" method="post" action="page1.asp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [document.forms](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/forms.htm#allgemeines).

You might want to tryout something like this:

```
function submitforms() {
    for(var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
        if(document.forms[i].onsubmit && !document.forms[i].obsubmit()) {
            return;
        }

        document.forms[i].submit();
    }
}
```

Please note I didn't check your code validity and reasonableness.